# Snow Leopard Terminal begins to execute Ruby installation upon launch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal

at some point after I installed Ruby on rails, my terminal on Snow Leopard began executing the configuration (?) procedure for Ruby.

```
Last login: Thu Oct 14 21:39:51 on ttys002
/Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #extracted to /Users/Adam/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p0 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #configuring
```

Any pointers will be appreciated =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have any pending RVM tasks?

If you are experiencing some issue with RVM, you can try to reset it and reinstall your ruby interpreters.

Comment: Thx for ur response. I am not sure if I had any pending tasks. How can I check? Thanks!